# Best way to compute a big Mandelbrot image

Tags: c#, multithreading, opencl, fractals, hyperthreading

I try to calculate a fractal image, and as the calculation could be long as the resolution increase, I was wondering if I could use Hyper Threading to calculate "tiles" of my final image and then have the result.
But all my tries to split Threads or Tasks ended by a slower calculation than the way I showed below (just brute force all values in a for loop).

Also, I don't have NVidia GPU, and I wonder I that kind of calculation could be fasten up by OpenCL ?

For now all whay I have is creating a Bitmap with a given resolution and number of dots per side.

```cs
    Image Generate() {
      DateTime n = DateTime.Now;
      Console.WriteLine("Generating...");
      
      Image img = new Bitmap(resolution, resolution);
      Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img);

      double step = ((px - mx) / points) * 0.5d;
      for (double x = mx; x < px; x += step) {
        for (double y = my; y < py; y += step) {
          ParseDot(CreateDot(new Complex(x, y)), g);
        }
      }

      Console.WriteLine("Dots parsed (" + (DateTime.Now - n).TotalMilliseconds + ")");

      pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = img;
      pictureBox1.Refresh();
      isComputing = false;
      return img;
    }
```

[My result so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7CyC.png)

Thanks for any tips :)

Comment: When I did that a few years ago, I didn't calculate an image but a 2d array of int, I think (or maybe float). The rows could be accessed in parallel.

Comment: Where's the "hyperthreading" version of your code?

Comment: BTW, to "fasten" means to tie or secure. "Hasten" is the word meaning to speed things up.

Answer (score 0):

With OpenCL you can do the mandelbrot zoom in real time, several hundred times faster than with CPU multithreading. The idea is to compute each pixel on the Bitmap with 1 GPU thread, i.e. parallelize your nested `x` and `y` loops. Example source code (Java & OpenCL via Aparapi) as well as executable `.jar` samples are [on my website](http://projectphysx.epizy.com/mandelbrot.html).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I finally found a way to hyper thread, I'll defintly have a look about OpenCL later, but for now I manage to divide calculation time by 5 using Parallel.For() :

```cs
      double span = (Form1.px - Form1.mx);
      int parallels = 50;
      List<Dot>[] dots = new List<Dot>[parallels];

      Parallel.For(0,
        parallels,
        (iteration, state) => {
          dots[iteration] = new List<Dot>();
          for (double x = Form1.mx + (span / parallels) * iteration; x < Form1.mx + (span / parallels) * (iteration + 1); x += step) {
            for (double y = Form1.my; y < Form1.py; y += step) {
              dots[iteration].Add(CreateDot(new Complex(x, y)));
            }
          }
        });
```